# insert data into database using button tag of html in asp . net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

when i enter value it send error the resources can not be found

error: 
Server Error in '/' Application.

how to solve this 
controller

```
public ActionResult Registration_()
            {
                Registration Registration = new Registration();
                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public ActionResult Registration_(Registration reg)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    DB.Registrations.Add(reg);
                    DB.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
```

Views(error is in view)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <div class="col-md-6 account">

                    <h3>Login</h3>
                    <label for="">Username or email address *</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Ex: Name" } })
                    </div>
                    <label for="">Password *</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Passwords, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Ex: Name" } })
                    </div>
                    <button>Login</button>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
                    <input type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever"><span>Remember me</span>
                    <br /><br />
                    <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 account">

                    <h3>Register</h3>
                    <label for=""> Email address *</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Ex: Name" } })
                    </div>
                    <label for="">Password *</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Passwords, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Ex: Name" } })
                    </div>
                    <label for="">Register As *</label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.DropDownList("dropRoles", new List<SelectListItem>()
                   {
                       new SelectListItem() { Text= "Register As", Selected = true },
                       new SelectListItem() { Text= "Employer", Value = "true" },
                       new SelectListItem() { Text= "Employee", Value = "false" }
                   })
                        @*<select class="form-control">
            <option value="">Employer </option>
            <option value="">Candidate </option>
        </select>*@     
                    </div>

                    <button>SignUp/Register</button>
                </div>
    }
```

i think when i submit or signup then he is not get way. 
whatever anyone can explain and resolve it?
i shall be very thankful.

Comment: Can you show your Registration model code.

Comment: public partial class Registration
    {
        public int RegistrationID { get; set; }
        public string RegEmail { get; set; }
        public string Passwords { get; set; }
        public bool RegisterAsID { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public partial class Registration
    {
        public int RegistrationID { get; set; }
        public string RegEmail { get; set; }
        public string Passwords { get; set; }
        public bool RegisterAsID { get; set; }
    }